# bitwise operations between elements in a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, bit-manipulation

I have a of list of bitwise elements, e.g. [1,1,1], and I want to do a bitwise OR operation between every element in the list.  So, e.g.

for [1,1,1] do

1 | 1 | 1 = 1

or for [1,17,1] do

1 | 17 | 1 = 17

How can I do this without looping?  Numpy's bitwise_or only seems to work on 2 arrays.  Is there a bitwise & or | that works on every element, similar to sum, or np.mean?   Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works for [numpy reduce](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html):

```
>>> ar = numpy.array([1,17,1])
>>> numpy.bitwise_or.reduce(ar)
17
```

Answer (score 30):

You can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) with [`operator.ior`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.ior):

```
>>> from operator import ior
>>> lst = [1, 17, 1]
>>> reduce(ior, lst)
17
```

And as suggested by @DSM in comments the numpy equivalent will be:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array(lst)
>>> np.bitwise_or.reduce(arr)
17
```

Comment: With the numpy equivalent `np.bitwise_or.reduce(arr)`.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that if you are using numpy you should use numpy's solutions as much as possible because they are usually tuned for performance.

Answer (score 3):

Without importing anything, neither `numpy` nor `operator.ior`, as suggested in  the other answers:

```
a = [1,17,1]
reduce(lambda x,y: x | y, a)
```

Edit: However, when I benchmarked different options, this was faster:

```
a = [1,17,1]; b = 0
for x in a: b |= x
```

This second option also has the advantage that it works in Python 3, from which `reduce` has been eliminated (although it can still be imported from `functools`).

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, `reduce` is no longer a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) can be used in conjunction with [`operator.or_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.or_) instead.

```py
from functools import reduce
import operator
l = [1, 17, 1]
result = reduce(operator.or_, l)
print(result) # 17
```

Alternatively, the following solution can be used just for ints:

```py
from functools import reduce
l = [1, 17, 1]
result = reduce(int.__or__, l)
```