# bitwise "&"ing an unspecified number of dataframe masks?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logical-operators

So I'm used to combining dataframe masks like so:
`final_mask = mask1 & mask2`

But what if I want to combine many masks? For example, the list:
`[mask1, mask2, mask3, mask4, ..., mask20]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528328/numpy-logical-or-for-more-than-two-arguments (`np.logical_and.reduce(masks)`)

Comment: and, https://stackoverflow.com/a/25796271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas cookbook solution](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#building-criteria), last paragraph with [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : [4,5,6,7], 'BBB' : [10,20,30,40],'CCC' : [100,50,-30,-50]})
print (df)
   AAA  BBB  CCC
0    4   10  100
1    5   20   50
2    6   30  -30
3    7   40  -50

mask1 = df.AAA <= 5.5
mask2 = df.BBB == 10.0
mask3 = df.CCC > -40.0

masks = [mask1, mask2, mask3]
mask = functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x & y, masks)

print (df[mask])
   AAA  BBB  CCC
0    4   10  100
```

Another solution from [`ayhan`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45577120/bitwise-ing-an-unspecified-number-of-dataframe-masks#comment78113625_45577120) comment working on `1d` mask (masks are `Series`):

```
mask = np.logical_and.reduce(masks)

print (df[mask])
   AAA  BBB  CCC
0    4   10  100
```

As [ayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45577120/bitwise-ing-an-unspecified-number-of-dataframe-masks#comment78113860_45577139) pointed, first solution  also works with `2D` masks:

```
mask1 = df <= 5.5
mask2 = df < 1.0
mask3 = df > -40.0

masks = [mask1, mask2, mask3]
mask = functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x & y, masks)
print (mask)
     AAA    BBB    CCC
0  False  False  False
1  False  False  False
2  False  False   True
3  False  False  False
```

---

```
mask = np.logical_and.reduce(masks)
print (mask)
```

> ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 4 to array axis with dimension 3

Comment: I couldn't make `np.logical_and.reduce(masks)`  work on 2D masks. Yours works though.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the easiest way is using a `for` loop:

```
final_mask = mask1
for mask in [mask2, mask3, mask4]:
    final_mask = final_mask & mask
```

Notice though that, although it is easy to understand, this way may not be considered the most "pythonic" way. Using `reduce`, as pointed by others, makes your code shorter but may not be easier to read by novices.

Comment: This way is perfectly Pythonic. There's a reason `reduce` was moved out of the global namespace...